# How do I set meta tags using php in a Magento module?

Tags: magento

This doesn't work in my `.phtml` file.

```
$head = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
$head->setTitle("title blah");
$head->setDescription("description goes here");
$head->setKeywords("apples bananas coconuts");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you are going to want to put that code into your controller, not your view files.